# Wordpress page ends up on phpinfo

Tags: php, wordpress

I've set up a WP site locally (we use the site in production), I've updated the db to point to `localhost` using [these queries](https://www.5balloons.info/migrate-setup-live-wordpress-site-localhost/)

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value, 'http://www.yoursitename.com', 'http://localhost') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl';
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content, 'http://www.yoursitename.com', 'http://localhost');
UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'http://www.yoursitename.com','http://localhost');
```

and the front page loads mostly correctly - some pictures are missing and some indents are off.

I have a problem however when I try to got to any page, for example `/free-trial`, in which case `phpinfo` loads. I verified that in the db under `wp_posts` the `free-trial` page exists and if I log in as `wp-admin` I can see the right content under the `Pages` tab.

This is the whole content of the `.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
<IfModule LiteSpeed>
RewriteEngine on
CacheLookup on
RewriteRule .* - [E=Cache-Control:no-autoflush]
RewriteRule ^min/\w+\.(css|js) - [E=cache-control:no-vary]

### marker CACHE RESOURCE start ###
RewriteRule wp-content/.*/[^/]*(responsive|css|js|dynamic|loader|fonts)\.php - [E=cache-control:max-age=3600]
### marker CACHE RESOURCE end ###

### marker FAVICON start ###
RewriteRule favicon\.ico$ - [E=cache-control:max-age=86400]
### marker FAVICON end ###

</IfModule>
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END LSCACHE
# BEGIN NON_LSCACHE
## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
### marker MINIFY start ###
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)/min/(\w+)\.(css|js)$
RewriteCond %1/wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 -f
RewriteRule min/(\w+)\.(css|js) wp-content/cache/$2/$1.$2 [L]
</IfModule>
### marker MINIFY end ###

## LITESPEED WP CACHE PLUGIN - Do not edit the contents of this block! ##
# END NON_LSCACHE

# BEGIN HTTPS Redirection Plugin
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
# END HTTPS Redirection Plugin

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php56” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

  [1]: https://www.5balloons.info/migrate-setup-live-wordpress-site-localhost/
```

I can't figure out what goes wrong. What is the life-cycle in WP when a page is requested?

**Update**

I found the issue: in Xampp I've set up several websites in htdocs, like

```
htdocs\site1
htdocs\site2
```

When I was accessing `http:\\localhost\site1` and clicked a link to `http:\\localhost\site1\free-trial` it ended up loading the `index.php` from the `htdocs` folder.

I have not yet figured out the proper way to access the sub-urls but it I think I should mingle with the rewrite rules.

**UPDATE**

I ended up changing the relatively complex rewrite rules to something simple, which works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Have you checked your `index.php`? Or `grep`ped through the entire installation for `phpinfo`? WordPress shouldn't be doing this on its own, so it's likely something that was added at some point, either for testing/debugging or maliciously by someone trying to gain info about your system. (I'd bet on the former.)

Comment: I guess that it was some unauthorized access and someone trying to do malicious stuff

Comment: Since this isn't happening on the home page then I suggest - look at your themes folder that you are using and check page.php and functions.php.

Comment: If you can access the backend, try going to Settings > Permalinks and then click save. That may work.